# Is it possible to add/remove class property from :before and :after CSS elements?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to make jQuery functions (`addClass` and `removeClass`) affect `:after` and `:before` elements in CSS?

```
.accordion-heading > a:before {
    background: url(../images/menuleftarrow.png) 98% center no-repeat;
} 
.accordion-heading .accordion-toggle > a:after {
    background: url(../images/menudownarrow.png) 98% center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not directly possible because pseudo elements such as `:before` and `:after` do not exist in the DOM.

The workaround is to add or remove the class on the parent element and then use that to key changes in your CSS, something like this:

```
$('.accordion-toggle a').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.accordion-heading .accordion-toggle > a.foo:after {
    background: none; /* hide the background */
}
```

Comment: i just use a collaps fuction in my left menu,,

Comment: how can i put a + and - image right side of the menu for knowing submenus

Comment: You just need to change the `background-image` property to point to the URL of the appropriate image.

Comment: @ShanuShaji I would start a new question for that. This question is asking 'is it possible' not how to achieve it.

Comment: Am not a expert am a beginer